# Android call quality

Tags: android, call, qos

it's possible to get or to measure the call quality during a voice call in Android?

The ideia is to know the distribution of quality audio during a call by location.

Answer (score 0):

You mean the kb/s of the audio signal? " call quality" is something that differs per person IMO. Background noise cancelling has a huge impact on call quality for example, but not on the kb/s.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a specific metric for *call quality*. It could range from anything to anything, really: number of dropped frames, signal to noise ratio (not sure how you would get it), spectrum analysis, something subjective like a study and so on. Usually, the result will be a multi-dimensional feature space of all of above and more. Then you could start running algorithms for classification. You have exactly to know what you measuring. Otherwise *call quality* could mean close to nothing.

Comment: You are right, but what metrics that is possible to get on Android?

Comment: Like I said, you have to come up with conceptual metrics first, and then see whether they're testable on Android. You need to know how to map the concept of *call quality* to a number, and that's only up to you to design.